# How to solve problem with vikktorn library?

Tags: android, kotlin

My code throw a null pointer exception while opening the file state.json from input Stream. It show the error of Null pointer exception on AssetManager .help to resolve this issue

```
 @Throws(JSONException::class)
fun getStateJson() {
    var json: String? = null
    try {
        val application = Application()


            val inputStream = application.assets.open("states.json")

        val size = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        json = buffer.toString()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)
    val events = jsonObject.getJSONArray("states")
    for (j in 0 until events.length()) {
        val cit = events.getJSONObject(j)
        val stateData = State()
        stateData.stateId = cit.getString("id").toInt()
        stateData.stateName = cit.getString("name")
        stateData.countryId = cit.getString("country_id").toInt()
        stateobject.add(stateData)
    }
}
```

this is my method in which the exception is comming. Help me please
this is my logcat my friend

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.officicalpractice, PID: 14217
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:88)
    at com.example.officicalpractice.fragments.Upload.getStateJson(Upload.kt:236)
    at com.example.officicalpractice.fragments.Upload.onViewCreated(Upload.kt:82)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Please [edit] into your question the LogCat output.

Answer (score 0):

I have got Solution of My question
i have just changed these two statements

```
val application = Application()
 val inputStream = application.assets.open("states.json")
```

into this

```
val inputStream = view!!.context.getResources().getAssets().open("states.json")
```

and my problem has been solved